# Проблема macOS и верстки

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, macos

В макос при наведении на поисковую строку в приложении react app появляется вот такая полоска, как быть, может кто сталкивался.

Если что такая полоска не прописана в стилях, она вообще не понятно откуда появляется…
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите [mcve], а то вообще непонятно о чём речь

Comment: Я не знаю как описать более точно. Просто вот на скрине видно серую полоску около курсора. Суть такова, что если курсор отвести в часть строки запроса, то потом триггерит эта штука

Comment: Тут просто сам код вставлять нет смысла, так как я не понимаю из-за чего и как вылазит

Comment: Зачем вы картинку в таком хорошем качестве прикрепили? Надо было качество ухудшить и ракурс плохой подобрать, ибо по вашей картинке слишком хорошо все понятно

Comment: Добавил еще один скрин, но по мне на первом лучше видно, что именно появляется

Comment: Действительно, полоска, можете добавить пример с вашим кодом где можно воспроизвести такую проблему? По скриншоту вряд ли можно будет вам помочь.

Comment: Там слишком много кода, и ничего особенного нет, я уже писал чуть выше. На Виндовс и линукс такого нету, понимаете.